# Delete confirmation dialog doesn't show up when I delete a file

Tags: nautilus, trash

In Ubuntu 12.10, when I hit delete it just deletes the file with no confirmation dialog.

And yes the 'Ask before emptying rubbish bin or deleting files' checkbox is ticked in on the behaviour tab in the files preferences

Is there something I'm missing??

Comment: You add that this was an issue for you in 12.10 as well.  Can you elaborate on that some?  (We are working on getting this re-opened now)

Comment: default behaviour: delete in nautilus moves file to trash without confirmation. Delete in trash not possible for a single file. Either empty trash for all OR you need to rightclick a file and choose delete. Both action ask for confirmation.

Comment: Ok, so I have just tried with a new install on a virtual machine and it looks like there is no warning dialog. It's odd, why is there the 'Ask before emptying rubbish bin or deleting files' check if it actually doesn't do anything??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to deleting Files/Folders in Caja, the most common file explorer in Ubuntu.

The “bug” is still around in Ubuntu 16.04. Except they don't see it as a bug: If you delete something terminally, you'll be asked (if chosen so in the settings). If it's ‘just’ about moving files to Trash, there is no option, and the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key is trigger-happy.

(Yes, I would prefer to be asked about that, too. All to easy to almost-delete a file. And who thoroughly checks his trashcan before occasional emptying?)

→ [see here for further discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469920/no-confirmation-prompts-when-deleting-a-file-or-a-directory)