# No confirmation prompts when deleting a file or a directory

Tags: nautilus

When deleting a file or a folder, I don't get a prompt requesting confirmation of the deletion (the way I'm used to with Windows).

Comment: Please be more specific, how did you try to delete the items? Via the terminal? With the keyboard? A script?

Comment: Also note that 12.10 is End of Life, and you should probably upgrade to something that still receives updates and security fixes.

Comment: As @ThomasW. says you should definitely upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu (right now — it's really ***very*** urgent)... But the behaviour this question is about is exactly the same on other (supported) releases. There's no reason to close this as off-topic.

Comment: An up-to-date answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1126737/43246

Answer (score 9):

Hi & Welcome to **AU**,

Assuming that you're trying this on nautilus but no through the terminal. Well there's a known **[Bug discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/95853?comments=all)** in place for a while now. Not sure what has happened to it yet though.

> Default behavior of deleting a file/folder is that; the moment you hit
>   <kbd>DEL</kbd> button; file/folder will be moved to **Trash** without
>   any further confirmation prompt. But when you use
>   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> together, it will for sure ask for a
>   confirmation since you're completely deleting the file out of the
>   system. Further the same, confirmation will be prompted when
>   **emptying the trash** or **deleting the file individually within trash**.

If you're not being prompted for confirmation while **emptying the trash**, **deleting the file individually within trash** or either using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> anywhere; make sure you've enabled the option which can be seen below;

- Open **Nautilus** -> **Edit** -> **Preferences** --> Navigate to **Behaviour** tab & de below;

[image]

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is a good option for people just switching over from Windows. I remember the old days, where Linux didn't care. It assumed you know what you are doing and just deleted it. :)

Comment: That options refers to "emptying the Trash" or "deleting files", but not "moving files to the trash". Most users coming from Windows would like to get a confirmation before getting their files trashed (actually, most windows users don't even know what happens to files when they are moved to the trash or that they can even recover them, they just see them disappear). I guess the OP may be referring to this last case which is not covered.

Comment: Quoting the Bug report (dating back to 2008 !! It's unbelievable): `However, this can be very annoying and dangerous bug to a common user - a user may have pressed "Delete" to move very important data to the Trash, and then, without realising the previous action have cleaned the Trash, so permanently loosing that information despite there being a two-step (and partially revertible) process.`  /SIGNED m(

Comment: this option is no longer available in the ubuntu 20. looking for a solution

Comment: This option is not available in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure behavior from nautilus preference. (Menubar-**Edit>Preferences** from nautilus)

[image]