# How to enable confirmation dialog on files delete in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nautilus

Now option "Ask before emptying the Trash or deleting files" was replaced to "Ask before emptying the Trash". So how to enable confirmation dialog?

```
Nautilus -> Edit -> Preferences -> Navigate to Behaviour
```

Comment: If you really don't care which file manager you use - you could try `Nemo` - it has option "Ask before moving files to the Trash" in `Edit->Preferences->Behavior->Trash` :)

Answer (score 2):

*Short answer* You cannot enable such confirmation dialog in Files aka nautilus. It is not (anymore) available.

*Long answer* A confirmation dialog that appears when you delete a file to the trash is not (anymore) available in Files, aka nautilus. The idea is likely that this dialog is not essential, because a normal delete-to-trash operation is reversible. Thus, an accidental delete is easily undone.

Currently, when deleting to the trash, an "undo" pop up appears. 1) This already warns/reminds the users that he/she has deleted a file, so deleting a file does not go unnoticed. 2) That pop-up allows to undo the operation. 3) Next to that dialog, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> also allows to undo the delete. 4) Finally, the file can be restored at any time from the trash, as long as that trash has not been purged by the user.

With all these fallbacks, developers probably did not feel the need to still have a warning dialog. The warning dialog has been retained only for irreversible actions, i.e., when permanently deleting (i.e. bypassing the trash by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) or when purging the trash.

Comment: just deleting files are somehow not ending up in my trash! What could be causing this?

Comment: @quanta, this appears to be a different question.

Comment: it is, can you or anyone help me with this? Couldn't find a thread on this though.

Comment: @quanta if they are not going to trash - aren't you asked about permanent deletion? If so and it's a NTFS partition read my COMMENT to this question - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253464/cannot-move-to-trash-in-ntfs-partition

Comment: "The idea is likely that this dialog is not essential, because a normal delete-to-trash operation is reversible." - then there is a problem, because I may have pressed button by mistake, unknowingly, or my cat did it. This can happen if used is mistaken about which window has focus. Delete key is used in text editors.