# Cannot move to trash in NTFS partition

Tags: 20.04, ntfs, trash

I made an NTFS partition for sharing files between Ubuntu and Windows.

I also made a Recycle Bin inside that partition. I can see the folder `.Trash-1000` that was created automatically; but, when I want to delete a file, only the option "**Delete permanently**" is shown.

When using nautilus as `sudo` it works.

I cannot move files to **recycle bin** cause the option only appears when using nautilus as sudo.

Comment: In the partition there is a Recicle Bin for windows and one for Linux, the one of Windows was created automatically by the OS, and in Ubuntu, when I deleted a file as sudo, another Recicle Bin was created, so there or one Recicle Bin for windows and other for Ubuntu. When I press delete the file deleted permanently

Comment: I've edit the answer

Comment: In case somebody DOESN'T have trash there - edit `/etc/fstab` - to the line that is mounting your NTFS partition/disk add an "option"  `uid=YOUR_UID` (find your uid by command `id` (yes, it's just `id`), lot of times it's 1000) resulting in something like `UUID=AAAEXAMPLEAEW /media/youruser/EXAMPLE ntfs defaults,uid=1000 0 0` then remount `sudo umount /media/youruser/EXAMPLE && sudo mount -a`

Answer (score 3):

Add `uid` and `gid` to the `<options>` section of your NTFS partition entry in `/etc/fstab` so that Ubuntu makes you the owner of the partition.

First, check your id by typing just `id` in the terminal.

```console
$ id
```

Then add your `uid` and `gid` as follow, assuming here as 1000 -

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxx /mnt/Data ntfs-3g defaults,windows_names,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Now, by using the `Disks` GUI application unmount and mount the partition. 
If unable to unmount then close all the application which might be using the partition like File Manager, Terminal, etc. 
If still not unable to unmount then Log Out and Log In to reflect the changes.

Cross-check it by `cd` into the partition and enter `ls -al` command.

Comment: Perfect! thanks